# Improving speed of code execution

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array:

```
myarray<-array(rep(1:5,3*99), dim=c(9,3,99))
```

and a function:

```
freq<-function(x){ 
    m<-names(which(table(x) == max(table(x)))); m<-as.numeric(m) 
if (length(m)>1){ m<-sample(m,1) } else m 
}
```

I would like to look at the second column of each matrix in the array, i.e. myarray[,2,] and determine the most frequent value in that column. If there are 2 or more most frequent values then I would like to select one randomly. To do this I wrote the above function and would apply it to the array using:

```
apply(myarray[,2,],2,freq)
```

This works perfectly, but the execution time is a bit slow.

I belive it is slow because the function generates a table and transforms the data structure.
Is there a more efficient way?

After doing a little bit of reading I found that tabulate() is the fastest way of getting the frequency of occurrences in a vector.

I got so far as:

```
f<-function(x){ 
    a<-which.max(tabulate(x))
if (length(a)>1) {a<-sample(a,1)} else {a}
}
```

But the `which.max` part does not work as it always returns the first value. Once I have the results from tabulate how can I get it to list the numbers that occur most frequently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nnet::which.is.max`, which breaks ties at random rather than taking the first value.

Comment: but this doesn't select the most frequent element. This is easy to verify: a<-c(1,1:10); nnet::which.is.max(a) returns different values every time although it should return 1.